# Uncountably infinite simplex

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, distribution-theory, simplex

Consider the set of all Kronecker delta functions in some finite dimensional vector space. For instance, in $R^4$, you get the set $\{(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1)\}$, which is a simplex.

Informal statement of the question: what if you do this in an $Lp$ space on the interval $[0,1]$?

Obviously this isn't the right way to phrase it, because a Kronecker delta function is equivalent to the zero vector in an $Lp$ space, as it has measure zero. But you could work in a space of distributions instead, induce the $Lp$ norm on that, and then use the set of all Dirac delta distributions on the interval $[0,1]$, yielding something like an "uncountable simplex."

Taken as a manifold, is this topologically or geometrically equivalent to anything more familiar? I thought it might be a hypersphere but that obviously can't be right, as every point is the same distance from every other.

You can also construct this as a direct limit, if you like.

Comment: Could you please clarify your analogy, and then your question? It seems you consider "all Kronecker delta functions in $\mathbf{R}^{4}$" to be a set of four functions, but the set of "all delta functions in $[0, 1]$" to be an uncountable set. Instead of $\mathbf{R}^{4}$, did you mean "all Kronecker delta functions on a set of four elements", and you're identifying $\mathbf{R}^{4}$ (as the space of functions on a four-point set) with $L^{p}$? And/or, instead of "Kronecker delta functions", do you perhaps mean _characteristic_ functions...?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding where you're hung up. I asked what you get if you take the set of all Kronecker delta functions on a finite vector space (a simplex), and then asked what the correct analogy is to this in an uncountable function space.